# При пустом значении поиска выводит всю таблицу

Tags: php

Написал скрипт поиска но при вводе пустого значения выводится вся таблица, как это вместо всей таблицы вывести сообщение типа "Запрос пустой"

```
<?PHP header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php

    // определяем начальные данные
$db_host = 'localhost';

$db_name = 'terminal';

$db_username = 'hsa89';

$db_password = '97153hsa';

$db_table_to_show = 'kvitancii';

$str=iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251", $_POST['str']);

$select = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `comment` (`str`) VALUES ('".$str."')");

// соединяемся с сервером базы данных

$connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)

or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

// подключаемся к базе данных 
mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db) 
or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());

// выбираем все значения из таблицы 
$qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT id, fio, adres, kod FROM kvitancii WHERE(id) LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['nmag'])."%'") 
or die(mysql_error("Запрос ошибочный"));

    // выводим в HTML-таблицу все данные клиентов из таблицы MySQL
    if (mysql_num_rows($qr_result) > 0){
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){
    echo "<table width='596' align='center' border='1' cellpadding='1' style='border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid white;'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='3' rowspan='5' align='center' valign='top'>ИЗВЕЩЕНИЕ Ф1</td>
        <td colspan='2' border:'1px solid black'>" . $data['fio'] . "</td>
    <td colspan='2'>" . $data['id'] . "</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='4'>" . $data['adres'] . "</td>
  </tr>
  <td colspan='4' padding='3px' style='font-family:Barcode; src:url(fonts/Barcode.ttf); font-size:30pt'>00:08020:0288022800::022808:000:::00020</td>
  </tr>
   ";
  echo '</table> ';
  }}
  elseif (mysql_num_rows($qr_result)<=0) {
    echo "<div>НАЗАД&nbsp;↻</a></div>";
    }
  else {echo 'jib,rf';}
    // закрываем соединение с сервером  базы данных
    mysql_close($connect_to_db);

?>
```

Comment: sql injection detected.

    $qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT id, fio, adres, kod FROM kvitancii WHERE(id) LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['nmag'])."%'")



используйте PDO или mysqli

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['nmag']r) and !empty($_POST['nmag'])) {
    // выбираем все значения из таблицы 
}else
{
exit();
}
```

а что такое

```
$select = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `comment` (`str`) VALUES ('".$str."')");
```

вообще не видно откуда берется **$str** хотя без разницы, не интересно.